# The cohomology $H^*(BU(n); R)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces

I am reading this [post, Prop. 2.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+Cobordism+and+Complex+Oriented+Cohomology#ThomSpectra). It seem that none of the argument is dependent on the we are working with coefficient in $\Bbb Z$.

Hence, let $R$ be a unital commutative ring.

> (I) Do the results for $H^*(BU, \Bbb Z)$ hold for $H^*(BU;R)$?
>
> (II) Are the arguments the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Alternatively, you can deduce the computation of $H^*(BU;R)$ from the computation of $H^*(BU;\mathbb{Z})$, since the canonical ring-homomorphism $H^*(BU;\mathbb{Z})\otimes R\to H^*(BU;R)$ is an isomorphism (this is true more generally for any space whose homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ is free and finitely generated in each degree, by the universal coefficient theorem).

Comment: Hi Eric, also, is it for Prop 2.1, that the generators are at degree $2k$?

Comment: Yes, it's a polynomial ring on generators in each even degree.